# How to sum up reflected numbers and the original numbers?

Tags: java, sum, numbers

If I wanted to sum up, say for example 123 and its reflected number, which is 321. How can I do that?

Here's my code that generates the reflected number.

```
while(number!=0){
    int reflectedNumber = number% 10;
    number /= 10;
    System.out.print(reflectedNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Right now, you're printing out the digits of the reflected number instead of putting them together to generate the full number. Once you have it, you can just sum the two:

```java
// Copy number to a temp variable so we have it later for the sum
int temp = number;
int reflectedNumber = 0;

while (temp != 0) {
    int reflectedDigit = temp % 10;
    temp /= 10;
    reflectedNumber = reflectedNumber * 10 + refletedDigit;
}

// Now you have both the number and the reflected number - sum them:
int result = number + reflectedNumberl
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep a backup of the original number which you can add to the reflected number after you are done with calculating the reflected number. Also, you do not just have to print the digits of the reflected number; rather, you have to calculate it as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 123;
        int reflectedNumber = 0;
        int original = number;

        while (number != 0) {
            int lastDigit = number % 10;
            reflectedNumber = reflectedNumber * 10 + lastDigit;
            number = number / 10;
        }

        System.out.println("The reflected number is: " + reflectedNumber);
        System.out.println("Sum of original and reflected = " + (original + reflectedNumber));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The reflected number is: 321
Sum of original and reflected = 444
```

Answer (score -3):

Just copy the original number in another variable and add it to the reflected number

Comment: That is not enough to make the code work since `reflectedNumber` is not properly calculated right now.